# Warning "Symbol TMemoryManager is deprecated" appears AFTER the compiler is done compiling

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I get several warnings in the "Messages" panel, AFTER I compile my source code, after compiler's [Success] message.

Sometimes it appears when I put the cursor over a keyword/variable and Code Insight pop-up appears on screen (after Compile), sometimes not. The appearance is random (the warnings may appear or not). Basically, it depends on the cursor position in IDE.

[Warning] W1000 Symbol 'TVariantManager' is deprecated
[Warning] W1000 Symbol 'TMemoryManager' is deprecated: 'Use TMemoryManagerEx'
[Warning] W1000 Symbol 'TSingleRec' is deprecated: 'Use TSingleHelper'
[Warning] W1000 Symbol 'TDoubleRec' is deprecated: 'Use TDoubleHelper'

[image]

Nothing happens when I double click the message.

Any idea what could cause this?

Since this appears after the compiler finished, I guess it would be one of the plugins I have (GExpers, CnPack, Andy's) but I haven't seen it until now.

Comment: The warning messages are clear enough. Something in your program is referring to symbols that have been deprecated.

Comment: Nope. The message appears RANDOMLY and AFTER the compiler said 'done'. I will upload a screenshot to show it. ALSO double clicking the warning should take me to the line that generated the message but it doesn't.

Comment: How can we reproduce?

Comment: I am working on this. But if this is caused by a plugin... Anyway, it is something that uses the compiles some legacy code AFTER the compiler finished compiling the source code. So, it must be a plugin.

Comment: So you need to isolate this. Looks like you shot too soon.

Comment: Try disabling Eurekalog

Comment: I believe what's happening is normal. You're expecting the compiler/IDE to emit the warnings during compilation and then finishing; what appears to be happening is that the compiler/IDE is collecting the warnings, finishing compilation, and then listing the warnings it encountered.

Comment: Warning are not always emitted for every compile because not every unit is recompiled when you compile - only units which have changed and *need* to be recompiled will be compiled.  Warnings are only emitted for units which *are* compiled.  The warnings aren't "random" - if you want to see them all then be sure to perform a *Clean* before you compile.  This will purge all of your DCUs and will recompile everything in your project, showing all of the warnings for all of your units.

Comment: I wanted to start this day by digging into this (to isolate the issue as David suggested) but now, after the night restart (I always restart my computer at the end of the day) the issue does not appear. I will keep the IDE turned on all day to see if the problem appears again.

Comment: Forget about that - It just reappeared!

Comment: @J...-I don't think it is related to that. The warnings appear every time I ctrl+click a keyword. I updated the screenshot to show that. Also, when I press ctrl+F9 the messages do not appear if the mouse is not over the code. They appear seconds/minutes later when I move the mouse over the code.

Comment: Your screenshot shows the usual messages that appear after a compile or build. I see nothing wrong there. You should be able to double-click these warnings and the IDE will take you to the offending place. I don't see you select a keyword anywhere.

Comment: @Rudy I don't think so. They appear earlier.

Comment: @Frosty Since you think it's a plugin, which one is it?

Comment: @David: I only see them after a compile. They may appear earlier, but in my case, the compiler dialog is modal, so I can't see them anyway. I see nothing wrong here.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan-The last thing I changed in the IDE was to update Andy's IDE Fix Pack: http://andy.jgknet.de/blog @ WarrenP: I disabled Eureka but nothing changed.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I cannot reproduce anything like the image in the question. Can you put one on an image sharing site?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I am baffled.That is the Build tab of the Message pane of the IDE. I assume you have one too. I can not reproduce the warning messages, of course. This one seems to be docked to the left of the editor (which is unusual, but irrelevant) hence the few red dots you see,

Comment: @Rudy So you can't reproduce?

Comment: @Rudy You are getting warning messages after the **Failed** or **Success** line, and those warnings have neither file name nor line number. And the messages before **Success** or **Failed** do have file name and line number?

Comment: I think I finally see the problem, sorry. The warnings appear *below* the **Failed** and *Elapsed time* messages, which is indeed unusual.

Comment: I just noticed what you posted just before you posted it. I get the problem, finally.

Comment: Ok. So other people can confirm the problem now.

Comment: No, @Rudy was not confirming that he saw the same problem as you, just that he now understands the problem. I think though that I do now have an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I have an explanation. Here is some output from the build window of my IDE:

```
Checking project dependencies...
Compiling Foo.dproj (Debug, Win32)
dcc command line for "Foo.dpr"
..... // spurious details removed
Success
Elapsed time: 00:00:05.2
[Error] E1000 Symbol 'TImageIndex' is deprecated: 'Use System.UITypes.TImageIndex'
[Error] E1000 Symbol 'CM_THEMECHANGED' is deprecated: 'Use CM_STYLECHANGED'
[Error] E1000 Symbol 'RaiseList' is deprecated: 'Use AcquireExceptionObject'
[Error] E1000 Symbol 'TMemoryManager' is deprecated: 'Use TMemoryManagerEx'
[Error] E1000 Symbol 'Release' is deprecated
[Error] E1000 Symbol 'ThemeServices' is deprecated: 'Use StyleServices'
[Error] E1000 Symbol 'faVolumeID' is deprecated
[Error] E1000 Symbol 'GetHeapStatus' is deprecated
[Error] E1000 Symbol 'THeapStatus' is deprecated
[Error] E1000 Symbol 'THeapStatus' is deprecated
[Error] E1000 Symbol 'THeapStatus' is deprecated
[Error] E1000 Symbol 'THeapStatus' is deprecated
[Error] E1000 Symbol 'THeapStatus' is deprecated
[Error] E1000 Symbol 'THeapStatus' is deprecated
[Error] E1000 Symbol 'THeapStatus' is deprecated
[Error] E1000 Symbol 'THeapStatus' is deprecated
[Error] E1000 Symbol 'THeapStatus' is deprecated
[Error] E1000 Symbol 'THeapStatus' is deprecated
[Error] E1000 Symbol 'THeapStatus' is deprecated
[Error] E1000 Symbol 'TScrollStyle' is deprecated: 'Use System.UITypes.TScrollStyle'
```

This particular set of errors appeared when I tried to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + click to navigate to the definition of a symbol in my source code. What happens then is that the IDE uses one of its internal parsers/compilers to understand the code and work out exactly which symbol this is. This internal parsers/compilers is written in Delphi and emits hints, warnings and errors which land in the main IDE build window.

I know that the specific set of warnings that you have seen differs in content from mine, but I am sure that the root cause is the same in principle. One of the internal parsers/compilers is spitting out these messages, and so they are completely unrelated to the content of your code.

Comment: "and so they are completely unrelated to the content of your code" - I imagined that since 'i recognized none of the classes/records shows in those warnings.

Comment: The question is: why it started to show these warnings now. I don't remember to have seen them before. In the last 3 days they totally stopped (again).

Comment: It's quite hard to pin down. Sometimes they appear, sometimes they don't. For me it depends on where I am in my codebase as to whether or not they appear. Presumably different aspects of my code triggers different routes through the internal parser/compiler code. In the end though, you simply have to ignore the messages. You know that they are not related to your use, and when you compile on the command line for a true build you won't see them, and the compile dialog doesn't include them in its count of warnings/hints. So it should not affect your workflow.

Comment: Just another Delphi quirk. Thanks David for helping bringing some light into this.

Answer (score 0):

Addendum to David's answer. Another thing that triggers this odd behavior is the Refactor. This is what I get after unsuccessfully trying to apply the 'Pull members up' refactor.

```
Checking project dependencies...
..... // spurious details removed
Success
Elapsed time: 00:00:01.9
[Warning] W1000 Symbol 'vmtEquals' is deprecated: 'Use VMTOFFSET in asm code'
[Warning] W1000 Symbol 'vmtGetHashCode' is deprecated: 'Use VMTOFFSET in asm code'
[Warning] W1000 Symbol 'vmtToString' is deprecated: 'Use VMTOFFSET in asm code'
[Warning] W1000 Symbol 'vmtSafeCallException' is deprecated: 'Use VMTOFFSET in asm code'
[Warning] W1000 Symbol 'vmtAfterConstruction' is deprecated: 'Use VMTOFFSET in asm code'
[Warning] W1000 Symbol 'vmtBeforeDestruction' is deprecated: 'Use VMTOFFSET in asm code'
[Warning] W1000 Symbol 'vmtDispatch' is deprecated: 'Use VMTOFFSET in asm code'
[Warning] W1000 Symbol 'vmtDefaultHandler' is deprecated: 'Use VMTOFFSET in asm code'
[Warning] W1000 Symbol 'vmtNewInstance' is deprecated: 'Use VMTOFFSET in asm code'
[Warning] W1000 Symbol 'vmtFreeInstance' is deprecated: 'Use VMTOFFSET in asm code'
[Warning] W1000 Symbol 'vmtDestroy' is deprecated: 'Use VMTOFFSET in asm code'
[Warning] W1000 Symbol 'vmtQueryInterface' is deprecated: 'Use VMTOFFSET in asm code'
[Warning] W1000 Symbol 'vmtAddRef' is deprecated: 'Use VMTOFFSET in asm code'
[Warning] W1000 Symbol 'vmtRelease' is deprecated: 'Use VMTOFFSET in asm code'
[Warning] W1000 Symbol 'vmtCreateObject' is deprecated: 'Use VMTOFFSET in asm code'
[Warning] W1000 Symbol 'TVariantManager' is deprecated
[Warning] W1000 Symbol 'TVariantManager' is deprecated
[Warning] W1000 Symbol 'TMemoryManager' is deprecated: 'Use TMemoryManagerEx'
[Warning] W1000 Symbol 'TMemoryManager' is deprecated: 'Use TMemoryManagerEx'
[Warning] W1000 Symbol 'THeapStatus' is deprecated
[Warning] W1000 Symbol 'THeapStatus' is deprecated
[Warning] W1000 Symbol 'HPrevInst' is deprecated
[Warning] W1000 Symbol 'AllocMemCount' is deprecated
[Warning] W1000 Symbol 'AllocMemSize' is deprecated
[Warning] W1000 Symbol 'TSingleRec' is deprecated: 'Use TSingleHelper'
[Warning] W1000 Symbol 'TSingleRec' is deprecated: 'Use TSingleHelper'
[Warning] W1000 Symbol 'TDoubleRec' is deprecated: 'Use TDoubleHelper'
[Warning] W1000 Symbol 'TDoubleRec' is deprecated: 'Use TDoubleHelper'
[Warning] W1000 Symbol 'TextStart' is deprecated
[Warning] W1000 Symbol 'GetHeapStatus' is deprecated
[Warning] W1000 Symbol 'RaiseList' is deprecated: 'Use AcquireExceptionObject'
[Warning] W1000 Symbol 'SetRaiseList' is deprecated: 'Use AcquireExceptionObject'
[Warning] W1000 Symbol 'Mark' is deprecated
[Warning] W1000 Symbol 'Release' is deprecated
[Warning] W1000 Symbol 'FPower10' is deprecated: 'Use Power10'
[Warning] W1000 Symbol 'GetVariantManager' is deprecated
[Warning] W1000 Symbol 'SetVariantManager' is deprecated
[Warning] W1000 Symbol 'IsVariantManagerSet' is deprecated
[Warning] W1000 Symbol 'UTF8Decode' is deprecated: 'Use UTF8ToWideString or UTF8ToString'
```

We can see again a reference to 'TMemoryManagerEx'.